# How to Add Logo/Client Slider in Bootstrap Website

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, slider

I am trying to add [a logo/client slider to a website I am working on (the one linked here)](https://codepen.io/mdashikar/pen/VWPvgE).

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

For some reason, it is not working. The only thing that I am getting after adding the HTML, CSS and Javascript code is a list of images with no animation. How can I integrate this code properly? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

it seems to work properly !! please check below:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.customer-logos').slick({
        slidesToShow: 6,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplaySpeed: 1500,
        arrows: false,
        dots: false,
        pauseOnHover: false,
        responsive: [{
            breakpoint: 768,
            settings: {
                slidesToShow: 4
            }
        }, {
            breakpoint: 520,
            settings: {
                slidesToShow: 3
            }
        }]
    });
});
```

```css
h2{
  text-align:center;
  padding: 20px;
}
/* Slider */

.slick-slide {
    margin: 0px 20px;
}

.slick-slide img {
    width: 100%;
}

.slick-slider
{
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
            user-select: none;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -ms-touch-action: pan-y;
        touch-action: pan-y;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}

.slick-list
{
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.slick-list:focus
{
    outline: none;
}
.slick-list.dragging
{
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand;
}

.slick-slider .slick-track,
.slick-slider .slick-list
{
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
       -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
         -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.slick-track
{
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: block;
}
.slick-track:before,
.slick-track:after
{
    display: table;
    content: '';
}
.slick-track:after
{
    clear: both;
}
.slick-loading .slick-track
{
    visibility: hidden;
}

.slick-slide
{
    display: none;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 1px;
}
[dir='rtl'] .slick-slide
{
    float: right;
}
.slick-slide img
{
    display: block;
}
.slick-slide.slick-loading img
{
    display: none;
}
.slick-slide.dragging img
{
    pointer-events: none;
}
.slick-initialized .slick-slide
{
    display: block;
}
.slick-loading .slick-slide
{
    visibility: hidden;
}
.slick-vertical .slick-slide
{
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
}
.slick-arrow.slick-hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="container">
  <h2>Our  Partners</h2>
   <section class="customer-logos slider">
      <div class="slide"><img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/luxury-letter-e-logo-design_1017-8903.jpg"></div>
      <div class="slide"><img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/3d-box-logo_1103-876.jpg"></div>
      <div class="slide"><img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/blue-tech-logo_1103-822.jpg"></div>
      <div class="slide"><img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/colors-curl-logo-template_23-2147536125.jpg"></div>
      <div class="slide"><img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/abstract-cross-logo_23-2147536124.jpg"></div>
      <div class="slide"><img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/football-logo-background_1195-244.jpg"></div>
      <div class="slide"><img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/background-of-spots-halftone_1035-3847.jpg"></div>
      <div class="slide"><img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/retro-label-on-rustic-background_82147503374.jpg"></div>
   </section>
</div>
```

Comment: It works as a snippet but for some reason when I copy-paste all of it into the HTML, CSS and Javascript files it doesn't function on the website. The only output I am getting is a list of images. How do I integrate this code correctly?

Comment: That is wired, I just did the same copy-pasted into the snippet editor it worked like charm, could you please share your implementation of code or any console error or networks errors

Comment: It works for me in the snippet editor as well, but it doesn't work when I copy paste it into my Bootstrap 4 website files. I copy the first part of the HTML code (<script> into the <head> section, then I copy everything from <div class="container"> onwards into the section where I want the slider. Then I copy everything from the CSS into my CSS file and everything from Javascript into my Javascript file. Maybe I need to change the filename of what I am linking to?

Comment: [This is what I am getting instead of an animated slider](https://imgur.com/a/HXs1UIG)

Comment: there is heavy chance that existing CSS overrides the CSS of this slider, please try to add the css in the right place so that it is not overridden

Comment: Yes, there is a high chance that [the theme/template I am using](https://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/new-age/) is overlapping somehow with the code I am adding. What's the easiest way to make sure this doesn't happen? Should I make different CSS and Javascript files and link to those instead?

Comment: Yes create a separate CSS file and include the file after the temple CSS, or add the css to head in style tag this easily overrides the template CSS.

Comment: This still doesn't affect it, it seems that I am doing something wrong because there is a disconnect between the HTML code (starting at <div class="container">) and the rest of the code in CSS and Javascript.

I have tried writing '<link href="css/slider.css" rel="stylesheet">'  in the <head> section but it doesn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue, I was loading the jQuery after the slider and changing it to above make the slider work as in the snippet

Here is a snippet running on bootstrap 4.0
https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/Q0Z1j